# CSS how to add space when minimising the screen in the responsive mode?

Tags: html, css

So we have this html page,

```
 <div class="mySlides" *ngIf="index == currentIndex">
      <div *ngIf="hr">
      <div class="slide-container slide-half" data-aos="fade-down" [innerHTML]="slide.titres.contenu | safeHtml"></div>
      <div class="slide-container slide-half text-white" data-aos="fade-down" [innerHTML]="slide.paragraphes.titre | safeHtml"> </div>
      </div>
      <div  *ngIf="!hr">
        <div class="slide-container slide-half" [innerHTML]="slide.titres.contenu | safeHtml"></div>
        <div class="slide-container slide-half text-white" [innerHTML]="slide.paragraphes.titre | safeHtml"> </div>
        </div>
      <p [innerHTML]="slide.paragraphes.body | safeHtml"></p>         
    </div>
```

Every thing works fine in the desktop, but in the responsive mode (iphone X for example) the first line will be divided in 2 lines and these lines are too close.
How can add a space between them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use "line-height: Xpx"; for exmaple

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
   Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy<p>

p {
   line-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, but this is not wokring.Because it is the same line but it is divided  with the responsive mode in the smart phone navigator.